# What does "T =:= Int = null" mean in Scala?

Tags: scala

As in the following code.

```
class A[T] {
  def add(n: Int)(implicit env: T =:= Int = null): Int = n + 1
}

object A extends App {
  val a = new A[Int]
  a.add(1) // 2
}
```

I know that `T =:= Int` means `T` should be of type `Int`, but what does `= null` part mean?

---

**Note**: The example is made up by me. It'd be better if you can show me a proper usage of `= null` if it's not appropriate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`null` is just assigning a default value to the `ev`, just like you would to any other parameter.
It is a clever way to find out whether the type is actually an `Int`:

```
 def isInt[T](implicit ev: T =:= Int = null): Boolean = env != null

 isInt[Int] // true
 isInt[String] // false
```

The trick is that when compiler sees the `Int`, it will pass in the actual implicit value, and when it can't find one, it'll just leave it as default. 
So, by checking if `ev` is `null`, you can tell whether or not the implicit was available at call site.

Comment: So it moves the `Int` test from compile time to run time? Sounds like something to avoid.

Comment: @jwvh, not the test itself. See, the "test" is the search for a implicit if a value is not provided. In Dima's case is "perform" no test at all.

Comment: @jwvh granted, it's not very "mainstream", but there are some legitimate uses for it ... Especially, if you use less strict constraints than `=:=`. For example: `def foo[T](bar: T)(implicit ev: T <:< AnyRef = null)` lets you tell whether `T` is a value type, because you may want to treat it differently. 
It's not the type check that's moved to runtime, more like some additional compile-time information is carried to the runtime.